# Find root approximants for low-precision numbers

Tags: approximation

I want to be able to find low-complexity algebraic approximants to decimal numbers. For example, 1.41 can be approximated as a solution to the polynomial `x^2==2`. There is a Mathematica function `RootApproximant` that seems like it should be able to do this approximation. However, I can't get it to work. `RootApproximant[N[Sqrt[2]]` returns $\sqrt{2}$ correctly, but `RootApproximant[1.41]` doesn't - it prefers to approximate it as `141/100`.

Presumably I need to tell it to lower the accuracy it's aiming for. There is an option called "DegreeCost" that can be passed, but I can't work out how to use that to achieve my goal.

Comment: Note that `RootApproximant[1.4142, 7]` is `Sqrt[2]`

Comment: How about changing the precision of the input: ``RootApproximant[1.41`3]``

Answer (score 3):

Though `RootApproximant` is doing the right thing for $1.41$, if you persist to get some polynomial what about adding some random precision. Try this!

```
TrickApprox[loPric_?NumericQ, degree_?IntegerQ, degreeCost_: 2] := Module[{val}, 
  val = ToExpression@(ToString@loPric <>ToString@FromDigits@RandomInteger[{0, 4}, 8]);
  RootApproximant[val, degree, Method -> {"DegreeCost" -> degreeCost}]
 ]
```

Now test it for a cubic polynomial.

```
TrickApprox[1.41, 3]
```

> Root[-5765 + 7694 #1 - 2705 #1^2 + 104 #1^3 &, 1]

```
N[%, 3]
```

> 1.41

If you increase the `DegreeCost` using the third argument `RootApproximant` will try not to include higher degree terms in the approximation.